# Blanks in Crystal Report Using Sub-Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have tried all the related topics on Stack Overflow I could find relating to this problem.
So I hope there is someone clever that can assist.
This is the layout of my report:
[image: Report Layout]

Now as you can see Group Header and Details a & b contain Subreports. Details B however is suppressed and hide blank sections.
Now Group Header #1 is in the section ticked as Suppress Blank and Keep Together. I also went to each individual Sub report and set the details sections to Suppress Blank and also went from the main report right clicking on each subreport and set in the uncommon tab unticked the keep objects together as well under the subreport tab I checked the option to suppress blank sub report.

[image: Report with Blanks]

But as you can see there is still blanks printing as this is the info which is suppressed for a condition I have set....

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: have you tried `Supress Blank Section` ? I guess its not the problem of sub report but the section where sub report is present

Comment: "Now Group Header #1 is in this section ticked as Suppress Blank and Keep Together. "

Comment: On the contrary, to investigate, try dropping a few fields and see what data is causing it to print. There must definitely be something. Then you can write a condition accordingly.